# MySQL order string by characters first and numbers then

Tags: php, mysql

i have strings such as the below and when i do ORDER BY id_code i get

```
GDA.DSAETA.YSTA.1
GDA.DSAETA.YSTA.2
GDAD.DAD.YM.1
GDAD.DAD.YM.10
GDAD.DAD.YM.11
GDAD.DAD.YM.2
GDAD.DAD.YM.3
```

but what i need is to get the results order by characters and numbers starting with characters first and then the numbers like the below

```
GDA.DSAETA.YSTA.1
GDA.DSAETA.YSTA.2
GDAD.DAD.YM.1
GDAD.DAD.YM.2
GDAD.DAD.YM.3
GDAD.DAD.YM.10
GDAD.DAD.YM.11
```

i tried using CAST, LENGTH, regular expressions but i wasn't able to get the results like above

Comment: this is not ideal question. Be specific and post your question with some details or snipped code or image or log.

Comment: Please be explain your problem

Comment: Have a closer look  to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i edited my question, i think now  its more clear now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to explode string by dots. Last string you must cast to integer to get right order.

```
select * from tmp order by 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_code, '.', 1), 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_code, '.', 2), '.', -2),
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_code, '.', -2), '.', 1),
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_code, '.', -1) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Comment: its fine but it doesn't apply when i have less characters like DEE.1
DEE.10
DEE.11
DEE.12
DEE.2

Comment: Is possible split string to separate columns? Then you can simply use order by column1, column2 ....